# Duplicate values in read from file minibatches TensorFlow

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I followed the tutorial about Reading data with TF and made some tries myself. Now, the problem is that my tests show duplicate data in the batches I created when reading data from a CSV.
My code looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import os 
import collections
import numpy as np

from six.moves import xrange  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
import tensorflow as tf

class XICSDataSet:    
    def __init__(self, height=20, width=195, batch_size=1000, noutput=15):
        self.depth = 1
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.noutput = noutput

    def trainingset_files_reader(self, data_dir, nfiles):

        fnames = [os.path.join(data_dir, "test%d"%i) for i in range(nfiles)]
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(fnames, shuffle=False)

        reader = tf.TextLineReader()
        key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
        record_defaults = [[.0],[.0],[.0],[.0],[.0]]
        data_tuple = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults, field_delim = ' ')
        features = tf.pack(data_tuple[:-self.noutput])
        label = tf.pack(data_tuple[-self.noutput:])

        depth_major = tf.reshape(features, [self.height, self.width, self.depth])

        min_after_dequeue = 100
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + 30 * self.batch_size
        example_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([depth_major, label], batch_size=self.batch_size, capacity=capacity,
                                                                        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)

    return example_batch, label_batch

with tf.Graph().as_default():
ds = XICSDataSet(2, 2, 3, 1)
im, lb = ds.trainingset_files_reader(filename, 1)

sess = tf.Session()

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

for i in range(1000):
    lbs = sess.run([im, lb])[1]
    _, nu = np.unique(lbs, return_counts=True)
    if np.array_equal(nu, np.array([1, 1, 1])) == False:
        print('Not unique elements found in a batch!')
        print(lbs)
```

I tried with different batch sizes, different number of files, different values of capacity and min_after_dequeue, but I always get the problem. In the end, I would like to be able to read data from only one file, creating batches and shuffling the examples. 
My files, created ad hoc for this test, have 5 lines each representing samples, and 5 columns. The last column is meant to be the label for that sample. These are just random numbers. I'm using only 10 files just to test this out.

Comment: My hunch is that you end up reading entries multiple times, you don't stop at the end of the file but wrap around. If min_after_deque si comparable in size to the number of entries in the file, there is a good chance that two identical entries will get to be in the same batch. Because one remains in min_after_deque elements until it is read the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for [`tf.train.string_input_producer(fnames)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#string_input_producer) is to produce an infinite number of copies of the elements in `fnames`. Therefore, since your `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` capacity is larger than the total number of elements in your input files (5 elements per file * 10 files = 50 elements), and the `min_after_dequeue` is also larger than the number of elements, the queue will contain at least two full copies of the input data before the first batch is produced. As a result, it is likely that some batches will contain duplicate data.

If you only want to process each example once, you can set an explicit `num_epochs=1` when creating the `tf.train.string_input_producer()`. For example:

```
def trainingset_files_reader(self, data_dir, nfiles):
    fnames = [os.path.join(data_dir, "test%d" % i) for i in range(nfiles)]

    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(
        fnames, shuffle=False, num_epochs=1)

    # ...
```